# ERROR: Your feed is invalid (after update WP4.7) in custom types

Tags: posts, feed, customization

i have created a new custom type “companias” with pods framework plugin , this custom type have this own website with its feed news, and other custom post types i have created.

For example “fercam” company, it website

mysite.com/news/fercam

And it feed

www.misite.es/news/fercam/feed/noticia

Well, since WP4.7, feed is empty and “ERROR: This feed is invalid” is returned

The theme isnt the problem because standart feed runs well, something like that (wihout company custom post type) http://www.misite.es/feed/entrada

In WP 4.6.1 and previous always runs perfect

what is the problem?

Regards

Comment: You need to include the code on how you made the custom post type. No one is going to be able to help you unless you give us an idea of what is happening.

Comment: Hi thanxs! Problem is solved, there was a wp4.7 bug with custom post types feed, solved in wp4.7.1